# Simulating typing at the prompt in a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, gnome-terminal

How can I simulate the user typing a character at the prompt? Does Bash/gnome-terminal have a feature that would allow this?

For instance:

```
$ . some-script.sh
$ c
```

Above, I would run a script, and the script would type the letter "c" on the next line for me without any user input.

Comment: You can use tools like [tag:expect], [tag:pexpect], ...

Comment: You can use http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Comment: Do you need the script reads that "c" of the standard input?